# Android studio and c++

Tags: c++, android-studio, intellij-idea

I can't find c++ code style settings in my android studio. I try to import settings.jar of my colleague but it didn't affect. Reinstalling studio didn't help too. What I need to do?
Thank you.

[image: studio screen]

Comment: I think you need to install that language support from a plugin

Comment: Solved. I delete folder ~/.AndroidStudio3.1 and run stuido: it import's default settings.

Comment: Feel free to post answer below rather than as a comment